# possible to implicitly re-attach all nested domain objects to Hibernate session in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, grails-orm, httpsession

I've noticed that when getting a Domain object out of the HttpSession and attaching it back to the hibernate session, it does not attach any Domain classes that are properties.

For example, assuming Foo and Bar are both domain classes, and Foo is a detached Domain class has a property Bar this would fail:

```
myFoo.attach()
println myFoo.bar.someBarProperty //LazyInitializationException
```

But this succeeds

```
myFoo.attach()
myFoo.bar.attach()
println myFoo.bar.someBarProperty //Ok
```

Is there any myFoo.attachRecursively() or similar that would avoid the above?  For a simple case it isn't a big deal, but for a larger object graph it can be messy.

Note I realize that using HttpSession for this purpose is not best practice, and I only use this in very specific cases via the flash scope, so please avoid 'Just pass the id and reload it' type answers :)

Comment: what cascade setting does the refernce to bar have?

Comment: Good question.  In my case, foo belongs to bar. Perhaps that is why it won't implicitly reattach.
static belongsTo = [bar: Bar]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to use **"myFoo.merge()"** instead of **"myFoo.attach()"** because when same object are associated with othere session at that time you get exception like :

**different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session error [duplicate]**

while you use merge() method at that time if object are persistence then it used that object and if the object is not persistence or not attach at that time it create new persistence for that particular object and use it.

[merge](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html)